# How to uninstall a package which can't be found in /usr/local/lib

Tags: python, flask, pip

I was following the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/) and at some point installed an 'incomplete' version of the `flaskr` micro-blogging app. I would like to 'overwrite' this installation with one obtained from https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr.

However, in the directory `~/dev/scratch/flask/examples/flaskr`, if I try to run

```
sudo pip install --editable .
```

I get the following:

```
The directory '/home/kurt/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/kurt/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Obtaining file:///home/kurt/dev/scratch/flask/examples/flaskr
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flaskr==0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask->flaskr==0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask->flaskr==0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask->flaskr==0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask->flaskr==0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask->flaskr==0.0.0)
Installing collected packages: flaskr
  Found existing installation: flaskr 0.0.0
    Can't uninstall 'flaskr'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py develop for flaskr
Successfully installed flaskr
```

Apparently, `pip` found an 'existing installation' which it can't uninstall. I'd like to 'wipe out' this installation; however, if I try search for it using, in the directory `/usr/local/lib`,

```
find . -name '*flaskr*'
```

the only result I get is

```
./python2.7/dist-packages/flaskr.egg-link
```

If I `rm` this file, it seems to 'come back' automatically.

How can I re-install the 'flaskr' app cloned from its Github repository?

Comment: With your virtualenv activated you could try to override it with "python setup.py install --force"

Comment: I tried this but it seems still not to work. (My 'test' is by running the `flask initdb` command, which is not recognized in the 'incomplete' version of `flaskr`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going back to the directory I had installed the 'incomplete' version of `flaskr` from, and running the command

```
sudo python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

which produced the confirmation

```
running develop
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskr.egg-link (link to .)
Link points to ['/home/kurt/dev/scratch/flask/examples/flaskr', '.']: uninstall aborted
```

Then, going back to the directory with the 'complete' version (`~/dev/scratch/flask/examples/flaskr`), I ran `sudo pip install --editable .` followed by `export FLASK_APP=flaskr`. Then the command

```
flask initdb
```

prints the expected output

```
Initialized the database.
```